# How would I grab the data from a combobox in a second window in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def nextwin():

    window.destroy()
    question2()

def clicked():
    choice=combo.get()
    if choice =="Apple":
        lbl.configure(text="Yum")
    elif choice =="Banana":
        lbl.configure(text="Yum")
    elif choice =="Egg":
        lbl.configure(text="Yum")
    btn.grid_forget()
    btn2=Button(window,text="Next",command=nextwin)
    btn2.grid(column=3, row=0)

def clicked2():
    choice2=Combobox.get()
    if choice2 =="Cheese":
        lbl.configure(text="Yum")
    elif choice2 =="Milk":
        lbl.configure(text="Yum")
    elif choice2 =="Butter":
        lbl.configure(text="Yum")
    btn.grid_forget()
    btn2=Button(window,text="Next",command=nextwin2)
    btn2.grid(column=3, row=0)

def question2():

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Which do you prefer?")
    window.geometry('600x30')
    lbl=Label(text="Which food is your favourite?")
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    combo=Combobox(window,values=myList1,width=15)
    combo.current(1)
    combo.grid(column=1,row=0)
    btn = Button(window,text="Click me when you're done",command=clicked2)
    btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
    window.mainloop()

#question possibilities
myList=("Apple","Banana","Egg")
myList1=("Cheese","Milk","Butter")

#gui basics
window = Tk()
window.title("What do you like?")
window.geometry('600x30')

#questions
lbl = Label(window, text="Which food do you like?")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
combo=Combobox(window,values=myList,width=15)
combo.current(1)
combo.grid(column=1,row=0)
btn = Button(window,text="Click me when you're done",command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

This is a code to take away the data from the chosen combobox examples and be used with the if statements to change the label to display something different for each different chosen reaction. The error I am currently experiencing claims that the second combobox on the second window requires a positional argument and upon research I have been unable to change this. Also I was wondering how I could take the answer from the if statements and bring it outside. So let's say I wanted it to save each response to all the questions and later have a unique response for you picking "banana" and "milk". Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined in `question2()` only exists inside of that procedure. So you cannot access them inside `clicked2()`. That's how procedures work.

You will have to pass relevant variables from `question2()` to `clicked2()` using parameters. Like so:

```
btn = Button(window,text="Click me when you're done",command=lambda: clicked2(window, lbl, combo, btn))
```

In `clicked2()`, receive all of those parameters.

```
def clicked2(window, lbl, combobox, btn):
```

Turn `choice2=Combobox.get()` into `choice2=combobox.get()`. Your can't use Combobox class as a variable.

In `clicked2()` your button is calling a procedure that is not defined in your program. Create a new procedure that will take `window` as a parameter.

```
def nextwin2(window):
    window.destroy()
```

In `clicked2()`, pass `window` as a parameter.

```
btn2=Button(window,text="Next",command=lambda: nextwin2(window)
```

to store the user's input, you can define a list in the main code and use append() function in `clicked()` and `clicked2()` to append (add) the choice to the list. Lastly, print the list.

```
def nextwin2(window):
    window.destroy()
    print(f"User picked {favts[0]} and {favts[1]}")

def def clicked():
    choice=combo.get()
    favts.append(choice)
    ...

def clicked2(...):
    choice2=combobox.get()
    favts.append(choice2)
    ....

favts = []
```